# Can i access 'dxdiag ' from powershell console

Tags: powershell-remoting, powershell-4.0

How can I access "dxdiag" with powershell . I want to run a script for gather some information from  a few remote computers.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the /x parameter, you can have dxdiag output to an xml file, which is then really easily parsed from powershell.  Basically just something like this:

```powershell
# Drop output in temp dir
$logFile = $env:TEMP + "\dxDiagLog.xml"

# Piping to Out-Null forces it to wait for dxdiag to complete before continuing.  Otherwise
# it tries to load the file before it actuallygets written
dxdiag.exe /whql:off /dontskip /x $logFile | Out-Null
[xml]$dxDiagLog = Get-Content $logFile
$dxDiagLog.DxDiag.DirectSound.SoundDevices.SoundDevice | ft Description, DriverProvider
```

Which dumps this for output on my machine:

```
Description                              DriverProvider             
-----------                              --------------             
Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio) Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Polycom CX700 (Polycom CX700)            Microsoft
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the command would run, and only later would it create the file.

```
(& dxdiag.exe /whql:off /dontskip /t `"$path`") | Out-Null
```

The problem is with the ampersand `&` which made the command exit before completion.

So either use:

```
dxdiag.exe /whql:off /dontskip /x $logFile | Out-Null
```

Or:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\dxdiag.exe" -ArgumentList "/dontskip /whql:off /t C:\Temp\dxdiag.txt" -Wait
```

From: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2116806-how-can-i-run-dxdiag-on-a-remote-pc